# Limit statement on Linq to SQL paged query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

is there any possibility to do this SQL statement in Linq SQL (ASP.NET)

```
Select * form users limit 23,100
```

without using another solutions like Loop,For ,....

Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 6):

The methods are [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882788(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882968(v=vs.90).aspx), for sample:

```
var result = (from c in Source
             select c).Skip(23).Take(100).ToList();
```

as a good pratice for paging data, you could have some parameters, for sample:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(int pageSize, int pageNumber)
{
    var query = from c in customers
                select c;

    return query.Skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you skip 23 then take 100?

Comment: yeah i wanna skip 23 and rake 100

Answer (score 2):

```
var usersList = (from users in db.Users
                 select users).Skip(23).Take(100);
```

where `db` is the datacontext.

should get the answer you want.

You will probably want to use an `orderby` clause as there is no guarantee the records returned will be the same order every time.

Comment: `LIMIT limit 23,100` does NOT mean take 23100 items.

Comment: @DavidG sorry, misread the question - fixed just as you commented

Comment: Great, now fix the capital P too :)

Comment: @AHmédNet this should skip the first 23 rows and then return the following 100 rows. You may want to add an orderby clause

Comment: Of course it could be simplified to `db.Users.Skip(23).Take(100);`

Comment: @user1666620 OP doesn't have an ORDER BY in his query either